# How to have multiple authentication cookies for a single app programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, authentication, web-config

I am writing a content management system where the user can create multiple sites inside the app.  Each site can have authentication.  I am trying to figure out how to have multiple authentication cookies for the app without having to add each one to the web.config.  I need to create them programmatically when the application starts up.  Is this possible?

Ex.

SecureApp: http://localhost/CTMS - Needs authentication to update sites

CustomSite: http://localhost/CTMS/Custom1 - Needs authentication separate from SecureApp

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this -

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket _ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(_version, _name, _issueDate, _expirationDate, _isPersistent, _userData, _cookiePath);

string _encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(_ticket);

HttpCookie _cookie = new HttpCookie("customticket", _encryptedTicket);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(_cookie);
```

Then you can write code to check incoming requests to see if they have this cookie -

```
HttpCookie _cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["customticket"];

if(_cookie){

_encryptedTicket = _cookie.Value;
FormsAuthenticationTicket _ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(_encryptedTicket);

    if(!_ticket.Expired) {
        IIdentity _identity = new FormsIdentity(_ticket);
        IPrincipal _principal = new GenericPrincipal(_identity, new string[0]); //Identity plus string of roles.
    }
}
else{
//dostuff
}
```

Comment: After writing the question, this is the approach I ended up going with.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent solution.  I've adopted this in one of our MVC 5 applications.

Comment: Where can I place the code that checks the incoming requests?

Comment: @hiFI This is old code which I wrote in the context of the original ASP.NET MVC running on the full .NET Framework. If I remember correctly I created a custom http handler which I added to the IIS request processing pipeline, though I would if I was implementing this now I would certainly be using newer technology such as ASP.NET Core.